# Compare two list in javers

Tags: javers

I have a question regarding list comparator. I have a web application which have page with table.
I can edit data in this table and also delete row.
Standard comparator working correct when i edit data but i have problem when i remove row.
The problem is common (i think) when i remove e.g one row what is happening
javers comparing old list with now one it's looks something like this:
old list have two object now list have one object (i removed first one) now javers don't know which object
was removed and he compare first object from old list with second object from new list and for him
whole object was changed and that is not true.

My thought was I will wrote own list comparator and in this comparator before javers compare method will be colled
i check if comparing objects have the same ID.
Unfortunately i have problem to obtain object ID.
My comparator looks like this

```
public class ListComperator implements CustomPropertyComparator {

public ValueChange compare(List list1, List list2, GlobalId globalId, Property property) {

    for (Object o1 : list1) {

        for (Object o2 : list2) {
            if(o1.getId().equals(o2.getId()) )  {
                javers.compare(o1, o2);
            }
        }

    }}}
```

The second list "list2" have my object from which i can get any property e.g ID.
The firs list "list1" is list with some ValueObjectId and i don't know how to get property with id from object o1.
Is there a way to get this information or maybe i'm doing something totally wrong please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have ValueObjects stored in those Lists? Since ValueObjects has no identifiers, there is no way to detect how they 'move' between List indexes when List is changed. Custom comparator won't help much without a
way to identify you objects.
I suggest to add some kind of identifiers to your objects stored in a List and map them as Entities (use @Id annotation).